# Adding a partition in Yocto Generated Image

Tags: linux, installation, embedded-linux, yocto

I am building an Yocto Image for Intel Board.

By default the image while installing creates three partitions:

- boot
- rootfs
- swap

I need to add one more partition to it for storing my initrd image.. Which is the place I have to modify..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Is this not a programming question asking which files to modify to achieve our requirement

Comment: @jww: The correct answer will probably be to modify some python scripts, so it is a programming question

Comment: Thanks Nayfe.. As we need to modify python scripts to achieve our requirement

Answer (score 1):

You need to check which `WKS_FILE` is used with `bitbake -e | grep ^WKS_FILE=`. You can look [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-kickstart) for more informations on how to use WIC.

Comment: The problem is WKS File is used when we need to install directly on the hardware. But I have an board with EMMC which I need to install using .hddimg format

Comment: WIC allows you to create any time of images, with very flexible partition handling. You probably can flash wic image the same way you do with hddimg. See [generic-bootdisk.wks.in](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel/tree/wic/generic-bootdisk.wks.in) for instance.

Comment: How do you flash your eMMC with hddimg file?

Comment: bootable usb using dd command of hddimg file and then click on install

Comment: Maybe use isoimage-isohybrid wic plugin to keep same workflow

Comment: I don't think so, as it only creates a bootable image and not installable one